# email text passed to a function is interpreted as a class

Tags: google-apps-script

I am passing an email address text variable to a function.

only when I pass a text with "org." in it, it is interpreted as a class

```
function main()
{
  var email = "name@surname.org.il";
  receiveemail(email);
}

function receiveemail(email)
{
  Logger.log('received a new email %s', email);
}
```

meaning, the email variable in function receiveemail looks like this:

```
"name@surname.(class)"
```

then I tried to pass the email as a text array

```
function main()
{
  var Text = new Array();
  Text[0] = "name@surname.";
  Text[1] = "org.";
  Text[2] = "il";
  receiveemail(Text);
}
```

and got this:

```
["name@surname.", "(class)", "il"]
```

finally, I tried this:

```
function main()
{
  var Text = new Array();
  Text[0] = "name@surname.";
  Text[1] = "org";
  Text[2] = ".il";
  receiveemail(Text);
}
```

and got this:

```
["name@surname.", "org", ".il"]
```

So, it's pretty clear that "org." is reserved somehow...

the question is, is there a way to avoid this, other than having to split the email address into a text array, with the dots placed in the correct position in order for the interpreter not to recognize the "org." as a class?

Thanks

Comment: I could not replicate this issue. See https://ibb.co/wgd3M4K

Answer (score 1):

It a visual bug. It just looks like certain keywords like `org` ,`com` are changed to `(class)` in the debug console.  But the underlying string is not changed and works as intended.

Comment: Thanks...absolutely ridiculous :) I spent hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: There is a bug in Public Issue Tracker that is very similar, in this case is with com.au: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114358543